# Dynamic form title

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

Here is my simple code:

```
    function save_edit(res,table_color)
    {
        var the_form="details_"+res;
        alert(document.the_form.title.value);
    }
```

All I want to do is dynamically put the form from which to fetch the value of "title",
but the above code is throwing a syntax error.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be what you want

```
document[the_form].title.value
```

But I recommend you look in to `getElementById` and more importantly, jQuery. IN jQuery you might say:

```
$('form#details_' + res).find('#title').val();
```

To achieve the same thing.